# PHP XML List Crashing when calling too many rows

Tags: php

Im trying to write some php code that takes data from a MySQL database and presents it in XML format. Currently there are 11 rows of data in the database. 
Im using $_Get from the URL (domain.com/?Num=5) where 5 is the number of rows to present back to the user.

The code that does the formatting is:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < mysql_num_rows($result) ; $i++){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$output .= "<recipe> \n";
$output .= "<recipe_id>" . $row['recipe_id'] . "</recipe_id> \n";
$output .= "<recipe_name>" . $row['title'] . "</recipe_name> \n";
$output .= "<recipe_img_small>" . $row['thumbnail_photo_url'] . "</recipe_img_small> \n";
$output .= "<recipe_link>http://www.domain.com/recipes/recipe_detail.php?=" . $row['recipe_id'] . "</recipe_link> \n";
$output .= "</recipe> \n";
```

It loads and works perfectly fine when I call up to 5 rows of data\, however when I get to the 6th Row it crashes telling me the issue is with line:

```
$output .= "<recipe> \n";
```

I cant see any reason why it would fail, but have an inkling its something to do with the **for** statement.

Where should I start looking to fix this?
Many thanks.

Comment: It's telling you the issue is with that line, but what is the actual error message? :)

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I start looking to fix this?

You should study the error message and fully understand it. It normally tells you what to look into next. But first study the error message.

The line given might not be the exact position where the error is BTW., it can be around that line and/or before that line as well.

That is because not all errors can be located for a specific line (most can, but some parser errors can't).